# Principal Coordinate Analysis using similarity measure

Tags: r, python, pcoa

I have a large dataset in which most of the items are different from each other and few are similar. If I were working with a similarity measure, I would like to only compute the similarity of items that I presume to have a high similarity score and set the rest of the similarities to zero and have a sparse matrix. However, finding a principal coordinate analysis in Python (skbio) and R requires a dissimilarity matrix, where a zero would represent a pair of identical items (in some metric). Is there another way I could find a PCoA that uses a similarity matrix, so I don't have to compute all of the pairwise distances or set the presumably high ones to some arbitrary large number?

Comment: what about principal components instead of principal coordinates? In PCA, the matrix entries are inner products, so an entry of zero would indicate orthogonality, which sounds like it may potentially be suitable.